# Filter All using Elasticsearch

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch

Let's say I have User table with fields like name, address, age, etc. There are more than 1000 records in this table, so I used Elasticsearch to retrieve this data one page at a time, 20 records.

And let's say I just wanted to search for some text "Alexia", so I wanted to display: is there any record contain Alexia? But special thing is that I wanted to search this text via all my fields within the table.

Does search text match the name field or age or address or any? IF it does, it should return values. We are not going to pass any specific field for Elastic query. If it returns more than 20 records matched with my text, the pagination should work.

Any idea of how to do such a query? or any way to connect Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by query String

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Alexia"
    },
    "range": {
      "dateField": {
        "gte": **currentTime** -------> This could be current time or age or any property that like to do a range query 
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateField": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For getting only 20 records you can pass the Size as 20 and for Pagination you can use RangeQuery and get the next set of Messages

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Alexia"
    },
    "range": {
      "dateField": {
        "gt": 1589570610732. ------------> From previous response 
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateField": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by using `match` query as well . If in match query you specify `_all` it will search in all the fields.

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "Alexia"
    },
    "range": {
      "dateField": {
        "gte": **currentTime** 
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateField": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When you are using ElasticSearch to provide search functionality in search boxes  , you should  avoid using `query_string` because it throws error in case of invalid syntax, which other queries return empty result. You can read about this from  [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

`_all` is deprecated from ES6.0, so if you are using ES version from 6.x ownwards you can use `copy_to` to copy all the values of field into single field and then search on that single field. You can refer more from [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html).

For pagination you can make use of `from` and `size` parameter . `size` parameter tells you how many documents you want to retrieve and `from` tells from which hit you want to process.

### Query :

```
{
  "from" : <current-count>
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_all": "Alexia"
    },
    "range": {
      "dateField": {
        "gte": **currentTime** 
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "dateField": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`from` field value you can set incremently in each iteration to how much much documents you got. For e.g. first iteration you can set `from` as 0 . For next iteration you can set it as `21` (since in first iteration you  got first 20 hits and in second iteration you want to get documents after first 20 hits). You can refer [this](https://mindmajix.com/elasticsearch/pagination-and-retrieving-of-documents).

Comment: But this was not working for me. and if I want to search some number example need to find 123 should it exactly the same I mean if I enter 12 and cannot get the result ? any contain keyword is working for number search

Comment: @Oshini Which ES version you are using ? And Elasticsearch by default analyzes test field and not an numeric field . This number that you are searching can I know what is its datatype ? If it is a numeric field , then it will not get analyzed and in that case you need to search exact term. If you want to search for an integer field in such a way than you need to use an extra multi field which is not analyzed on it. Can you paste your mapping as well . And what exactly you are searching and what  should be your required output.

Comment: @Oshini Let me add that `123` and `12` are technically different tokens, Elasticsearch is not smart enough to understand that `12` means in this case "beginning of `123`". To tell it explicitly you would need something like [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.7/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).

Comment: "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },

Comment: Can I search my any I mean 23 or 12 should allow to show record. but the is long

Comment: For long datatype Elasticsearch does not analyze your tokens so, they can be search as a whole only not partially. Can you tell what you are trying to search and what result you want when you are searching by `id`. Elasticsearch only analyzes for `test` fields. I your id is like 123 and you want that when you want that when you search 1 you should get 123 , Then we need use explicitly "n-gram-tokenizer" on this field. So, need to know what you are searching and what you want in result.